# MIP iOS SDK error with libmat.a static library

Tags: microsoft-information-protection

I am facing following error when integrate latest **MIP iOS** SDK version [**1.12.61**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/version-release-history) in my iOS project. (But works  fine with previous release 1.11.72)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ODWPrivacyGuard", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libmat.a(ODWLogger.mm.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please let me know if this is an issue with MIP SDK 1.12.61 binaries and how to resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is saying that it is unable to find the relevant class in your project. You can try the following

1. In your Build Settings, check for **Valid Architectures** flag and verify which Architecture you want the app to work on
2. Now, search for **Other Linker Flags** and add **$(inherited)**
3. Delete Derived Data, Clean Build and Run

If it's still not working, just remember that Xcode is unable to find the required Class/method that you are referencing in your project. There might be many reasons why this might be the case, like forgot to add the framework to bundle, failing to check the target membership, failing to include the framework in **Link Binary With Libraries** under **Build Phases**, etc.

Start your debug considering this point.

Also, If you are using pods, might want to clean your pods. You can find plenty of guides online for this.

P.S: Please add your Xcode, MacOS, iOS Versions (both previously working setup and current) under your query.  This might be helpful for potential answer.